# ¿Cómo hacer consultas anidadas compuestas SQL?

Tags: sql

Espero que puedan apoyarme con lo siguiente, y que me ayuden indicándome si es posible hacerlo mediante una consulta Sql o si tendría que buscar otros métodos:

Dada una tabla con campos **Codigo** y **Precio**, quiero mostrar únicamente los códigos en donde los precios no coincidan

Tengo la siguiente tabla: tablaX

Codigo | Precio
001      | 56.90
001      | 56.90
001      | 59.00
002      | 32.30
002      | 32.30
002      | 32.30
003      | 10.00
003      | 111.5
003      | 10.00
003      | 10.00

la salida que estoy buscando

Código:
001
003

Aquí no se muestra el código **002** ya que todos los elementos de precio coinciden.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: ¿Has intentado con group by codigo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es usar `HAVING` que limita el número de filas de precios a una fila, y el valor de esa fila es `MIN()`, que sería el código.

```
SELECT MIN(codigo) AS codigo
FROM tablaX
GROUP BY precio
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Te dejo la [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qQm1yecSntuRDxX4FbbDei/2) para que lo veas.

Comment: Este código Funciona a la perfección, deberías marcarlo como respuesta correcta

Comment: Asumiendo que códigos distintos no pueden tener el mismo precio.

Comment: Gracias, lo adaptaré para utilizarlo